# tensorflow.dataset.shuffle = tensorflow.dataset.prefetch + then shuffle internally?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

According to the documentation of tf.dataset.[shuffle](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#shuffle), it will fill in a buffer with size `k` then shuffle inside of it. Tho I don't want the order of data to be changed, I want it to be buffered. Then I found there is tf.dataset.[prefetch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#prefetch), which says "This allows later elements to be prepared while the current element is being processed."

From the description I guess `prefetch` is what I want (i.e. pre-loading the data while the pervious data are being used in training), but while trying to look into the code of `tf.dataset.shuffle` to see if they actually call `tf.dataset.prefetch`, I got stuck in [these](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.4.1/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py#L3829-L3835) lines (paste them below), cannot find where is `shuffle_dataset_v3` defined.

```
      variant_tensor = gen_dataset_ops.shuffle_dataset_v3(
          input_dataset._variant_tensor,  # pylint: disable=protected-access
          buffer_size=self._buffer_size,
          seed=self._seed,
          seed2=self._seed2,
          seed_generator=gen_dataset_ops.dummy_seed_generator(),
          reshuffle_each_iteration=self._reshuffle_each_iteration,
          **self._flat_structure)
```

My major question is whether `prefetch` is the replacement of `shuffle` in terms of buffering the data, and it would also be nice if someone can point me to where `shuffle_dataset_v3` was implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. `Prefetch` is for buffering data.
2. `gen_dataset_ops`, and other `gen_xxx_ops` are not included in source code because it is automatically generated by bazel to wrap C++ implementation for use in python. You should be able to find these `gen_xxx_ops` code in your local installation. For example, `${PYTHON_ROOT}/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_dataset_ops.py`